# Export database table into EXCEL in laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, export-to-excel

i am using laravel5.6. i want to export database table data into excel file.
here is my controller code

```
    use Exporter;

    $business = Approvedemand::all();
    $values ='';
    foreach($business as $item)
    {
        $values.='<tr>
            <td>'.$item['id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$item['name'].'</td>
            </tr>';   
    }
    header('Content-type: application/excel');
    $filename = date('Y-m-d').'-approveList'.'.xls';
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

    $data = '<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
    <head>
       <!--[if gte mso 9]>
       <xml>
         <x:ExcelWorkbook>
             <x:ExcelWorksheets>
               <x:ExcelWorksheet>
                  <x:Name>Sheet 1</x:Name>
                      <x:WorksheetOptions>
                          <x:Print>
                             <x:ValidPrinterInfo/>
                          </x:Print>
                      </x:WorksheetOptions>
               </x:ExcelWorksheet>
            </x:ExcelWorksheets>
        </x:ExcelWorkbook>
    </xml>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
   <table>
      <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
     </tr>'
    .$values.
  '</table>
 </body>
 </html>';

 echo $data;
```

When i run this, excel file download but it display html tag in excel. i am not sure this method is correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

> ***When i run this, excel file..***

I'm assuming you mean call a controller function with a web route. Something like..

```
Route::get('/your/path', 'BusinessController@export')->name('export');
```

> ***i want to export database table data into excel file.***

You can use [Maatwebsite/Excel 2.1.0](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/2.1/getting-started/) for this.

**BusinessController**:

```
use App\Approvedemand;

public function export()
{
    $data = App\Approvedemand::all();

    return Excel::create('Approve Demand'), function($excel) use ($data) {
        $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) use ($data)
        {
            $sheet->fromArray($data);
        });
    })->export('xls');
}
```

This is just a basic example. You'd obviously want to include some validation here.

Comment: @user3406350 how did you make out with this? Able to resolve your issue?